# How to serialize an object that implements a collection but ignore that it is a collection?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a simple class that implements Map<String, java.lang.Object>

```
public class User implements Map<String, java.lang.Object> {
  private String _firstname;
  public String getFirstname() {
    return this._firstname;
  }
  private String _lastname;
  public String getLastname() {
    return this._lastname;
  }
}
```

And when I serialize it, I think jackson thinks it's a collection. How to make Jackson consider it a simple object and not a collection? I need the result as if this class does not implement Map<String, java.lang.Object>

Comment: I think you'll need to write a custom deserializer for this.

Comment: @MCEmperor ok, but there I see that it is necessary to write like jsonGenerator.writeStringField(); etc. for each member. Can I somehow say serialize all?

Comment: Please don't get offended, but `User implements Map` that looks like a faulty design. You might need a map, that's understandable, but for it's not necessary to implement all methods defined in the Map interface. You can use *Composition* instead of *Inheritance* (i.e. include a `Map` as a field). You don't need to be a phone in order to use a phone.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, it's all like that except for the case when you need to map properties for an SQL query